# Calculate of standard deviation for an Odds Ratio by standard deviations of probabilities

Tags: odds-ratio

Given the formula $OR=\frac{P_1(1-P_2)}{P_2(1-P_1)}$ for calculating the odds ratio ($OR$). How can I calculate the standard error of $OR$ based on the standard errors of $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the cell counts you can get the standard error for the $\ln(OR)$ (see for exampel [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio#Statistical_inference)) :

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{11}}+\frac{1}{n_{10}}+\frac{1}{n_{01}}+\frac{1}{n_{00}}}$

Using the [delta method](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/delta-method/), you can approximate the standard error of the $OR$ as:

$OR \times \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{11}}+\frac{1}{n_{10}}+\frac{1}{n_{01}}+\frac{1}{n_{00}}}$

Comment: But I haven't cell counts: n11, n10, n01 & n00